# Toshiba Cl15t-B1204 Factory Reset Issue | Can't Reach Boot Menu

Tags: toshiba-laptop, reset

I'm working on this little netbook for a friend and he doesn't know the password.

I've been trying to reset from the boot menu options. From the instruction manual on this device it says to hold F12 while restarting, and the menu should pop up. However, I am getting no such menu; it just boots to Windows.

Could it just be that my button is broken, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

> 1. Power off the laptop.
> 2. Power on the laptop.
> 3. As soon as you see the rotating loading circle, press and hold the Power Button until the computer shuts off.
> 4. Repeat this process a few times until you see the "Preparing Automatic Repair" screen.
> 5. Now you want to let the laptop boot to the "Automatic Repair" screen.
> 6. Click "Advanced Options" and then select "Troubleshoot".
> 7. Here you want to select "Refresh your PC", if you do not wish to erase data, or "Reset your PC" to erase all data and restore your
>      system.
> 8. From here just follow the screen instructions until the recovery is complete

This is a solution from the following post. This maay work for you as well.

https://forums.tomsguide.com/threads/failed-factory-reset-on-toshiba-laptop.170611/